# Other operator in calculation chain than combineLatest to avoid redundant calculations

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx

I've successfully migrated a larger Excel calculation to JS using RxJS. Any input data is represented as an Observable and subsequent calculations are implemented with `.map` and `.combineLatest` when any Excel formula uses more than one input.

This works great except for one problem. Here is a simplified example:
[image: Excel screenshot]

Three inputs (`a$=1`, `b$=2`, `c$=3`) are used in two different calculations (`$ab = $a+$b = 3` in the first, `$bc = $b+$c = 5` in the second) as intermediate steps to calculate the final result `$abbc = $ab + $bc = 8`.

When $b is now updated/emitting a new input value (e.g. `4`), $abbc is calculated twice - first when $ab is updated (resulting in the wrong result `$abbc=10`) and again when $bc is updated, resulting in the correct result `12`.

While the final result is correct, the intermediate calculation is both wrong and redundant. Is there any way to only execute the last calculation in case `$b` gets updated - while still also updating the calculation when `a$` or `c$` is updated (which would rule out the zip operator). I understand that this example can obviously be simplified to leave out the intermediate steps and calculated `$abbc` directly from `$a`, `$b` and `$c` - but in the real live example this is not possible/feasible.

Here's the running example in JSbin: https://jsbin.com/pipiyodixa/edit?js,console

Comment: `abbc$ = ab$.withLatestFrom(bc$, (ab, bc) => ab + bc)` effects the desired behaviour, but ... I don't fully grok the semantics in this situation, so this is a comment.

Comment: @cartant thanks. Unfortunately that wouldn't work as updates of c$ would be ignored until a$ or b$ would emit again. :-(

Comment: Yes. I see that, now. It will be interesting to see the solution. I can think of a rather unpleasant hack involving the scheduler, but ... there has to be a better way.

Comment: @cartant I hope so - scratching my head regarding this issue since weeks, but simply can't see any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that RxJS's behavior is correct by its design.

It really should first update `b` => `ab` => `abbc` and then `bc` => `abbc`. It processed values in streams.

What you want is to process values in "layers".`a`, `b`, `c`, then `ac` , `bc` and after that calculate final value `abbc`.

The only way I can think of is to make use of JavaScript execution context and a trick with `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)`. This way you don't schedule any timeout (in fact the real [timeout might be `> 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)) and just run the closure in another execution context after JavaScript finishes executing the current one.

The bad thing is that to avoid re-emitting values multiple times you need to cache even more (because of `merge()`):

```
var b2$ = b$.cache(1);

var ab$ = a$
  .combineLatest(b2$, (a, b) => a + b)
  .do(x => console.log('$a + $b = ' + x))
  .cache(1);

var bc$ = b2$
  .combineLatest(c$, (b, c) => b + c)
  .do(x => console.log('$b + $c = ' + x))
  .cache(1);

var abbc$ = new Rx.Observable.merge(ab$, bc$)
  .auditTime(0)
  .withLatestFrom(ab$, bc$, (_, ab, bc) => ab + bc)
  .do(x => console.log('$ab + $bc = ' + x));

console.log("Initial subscription:")
abbc$.subscribe();

b$.next(4);
```

The [`auditTime()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime) operator is the most important thing here. It triggers `withLatestFrom()` to update it's value while when it's triggered for first time by `ab$` or `bc$` it ignores all consecutive emits until the end of this closure execution (that's the `setTimeout()` trick).

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/zoferid/edit?js,console

Also, if you add `a$.next(5);` the final calculation is executed just once (which might be both good or bad :)).

I don't know if this solves your problem because as I said RxJS works this way. I haven't tested it on any more complicated example so maybe this is not the way you can use at the end.

Note that `cache()` operator was removed in RC.1 and there's no replacement for now: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks - this solved the issue and gave me the right start. I now created an operator and replaced my `combineLatest` calls with this new operator - see my answer below!

Answer (score 2):

Based on @martin's (correct) answer, I created an rxjs operator that does the combineLatestDelayed:

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.combineLatestDelayed = function(b$, cb) {
  var a2$ = this.cache(1);
  var b2$ = b$.cache(1);
  return a2$
    .merge(b2$)
    .auditTime(0)
    .withLatestFrom(a2$, b2$, (_, a, b) => cb(a,b));
}
```

This way, I only need to replace the original `.combineLatest` calls with `.combineLatestDelayed`:

```
var a$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(1).do(x => console.log("Emitting $a=" + x)); 
var b$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(2).do(x => console.log("Emitting $b=" + x)); var b1$ = b$.cache(1);
var c$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(3).do(x => console.log("Emitting $c=" + x));

var ab$ = a$
  .combineLatestDelayed(b1$, (a, b) => a + b)
  .do(x => console.log('ab$: $a + $b = ' + x))

var bc$ = b1$
  .combineLatestDelayed(c$, (b, c) => b + c)
  .do(x => console.log('bc$: $b + $c = ' + x))

var abbc$ = ab$
  .combineLatestDelayed(bc$, (ab, bc) => ab + bc)
  .do(x => console.log('$abbc: $ab + $bc = ' + x));

console.log("Initial subscription:")
abbc$.subscribe();

setTimeout(() => b$.next(4), 100);
```

Full JS Bin [here](https://jsbin.com/mipoqiyeja/edit?js,console)