# Observable is null when unsubscribe is called

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to return an observable that will return data as follows.

```
getRootGroupNodes(): Observable<Group[]> {


    return Observable.create(function(observer) {

        var groups = [
            { groupName: "Group1" },
            { groupName: "Group2" }
        ]
        observer.next(groups);

        observer.complete();

    });
}
```

When I try to consume it

```
   this._loadGroupsSubscription = this._apiGroupService.getRootGroupNodes()
        .retry(3)
        .subscribe(
        groups => {
            // do somethign with groups
        },
        err => { this._log.logMessage("failed to retrieve groups"); },
        () => {

            this._loadGroupsSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        );
```

I get `this._loadGroupsSubscription` is `null`. Hence an exception is thrown trying to call unsubscribe on undefined. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ? This should be basic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true the variable isn't assigned inside the callback. I think there're two ways to handle this:

1. Wrap unsubscription with `setTimeout()`:

   ```
   setTimeout(() => _loadGroupsSubscription.unsubscribe());
   ```
2. Add `.delay(0)` operator, which is basically the same trick:

   ```
   var _loadGroupsSubscription = getRootGroupNodes()
     .retry(3)
     .delay(0)
     .subscribe(
       groups => {
         console.log(groups);
       },
       err => { this._log.logMessage("failed to retrieve groups"); },
       () => {
         _loadGroupsSubscription.unsubscribe();
       }
   );
   ```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/sunicoq/2/edit?js,console

See a slightly similar question with explanation how this works: [Other operator in calculation chain than combineLatest to avoid redundant calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455579/other-operator-in-calculation-chain-than-combinelatest-to-avoid-redundant-calcul/40460900#40460900)